# Iniciar função Async

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async

Bom dia pessoal, não tenho muito conhecimento sobre async, e talvez alguém poderia me ajudar em relação a isto:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
            AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (result.Credential != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = result.Credential.UserId;
            DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                ApplicationName = "Drive API",
            });
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
        }
    }
```

Eu precisava de uma maneira de chamar esta função, só que não sei como eu faria isto, se alguém puder me ajudar.Obs: Ela se encontra dentro de um controller.

Comment: Isso é uma action, quem vai chamar ela vai ser uma view. Se você está tentando chamar ela manualmente, não é uma boa ideia.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx